# SQL Database handle class

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing a SQLite dabase handle class at the moment. 
The intention is to have simple functions to add/delete/rename columns/rows or add new tables and so on and so on.

It's quite a lot work to do, if I want to do this in the right way.

So does someone know a similar project?

And If no how to find participants for this?

Comment: I'm currently developing an android ORM : https://github.com/AndroidORM/androidorm. I was waiting for some help to continue the project. Let's talk further on GitHub

Comment: @Gaëtan I'm not used github. But I can't find much information about your project there

Comment: It's a project in order to reproduce the behaviour of Doctrine but for Android. I have not yet written any documentation about it. You have my email address on github profile, send me an email and let's talk further on messaging like Skype or other...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project : [greenDAO](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO) . It should be what your looking for.